# C-SCAN disk scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Does the moving head only moves in the direction of increasing track number or not in C-SCAN disk scheduling algorithm?

Comment: It's gotta move back sometime, or each track will be forever lost as soon as the head moves past it.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm#Variations, the requests are only served in one direction; the return seek time is wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C-SCAN disk scheduling algorithm, the head starts from one end of the tracks and moves towards the other end, servicing requests in between.
When we reach another end, the direction is reversed head moves towards its starting position without satisfying any request.

So we have motions in two directions. We only satisfy requests in one direction(this direction is usually in increasing order of track numbers), and we don't fulfil any request while returning.

So the answer to your question would be YES the moving head moves in the direction of increasing track number in C-SCAN disk scheduling algorithm BUT it also comes back to its starting position when it reaches the other end. Also, while returning it does not satisfy any request.